# Can't decrease the brightness of the transparent shader effect

Tags: uv, shaders, image

I'm trying to make a transparent plane in blender 2.8 that works in cycles. I want to reach the same effect that I have when I set up a background image with the transparency enabled. Below you can see how I have configured the shaders :

[image: not working]

Instead,below you can see how it should look like :

[image: working]

mine is too bright. I tried to change the strenght value,but I don't get the desired effect. What's wrong here ? thanks.

Comment: Not exactly sure what you're going for but perhaps a mix between a diffuse shader and a transparent shader would be better. The emission shader emits light, which will result in higher brightness.

Comment: can you add a picture showing how to configure the shaders ? very thanks. What I want to achieve is to have a sequence of images that I can move forward and at the same time i wanna see behind them...

Answer (score 1):

The following node setup still uses an emission shader, but ensures that it only affects the camera. The math node allows to control the transparency of the image. If you'd like to adjust the brightness you can add a *Bright / Contrast* node between the texture node and the emission shader node (*Add > Color > Bright / Contrast*).

[image]

Comment: This configuration does not work. it is bright as before.

Comment: @Marietto Have you tried adding a Bright/Contrast node and reducing the brightness?